# I am creating a list and need to return the initial value

Tags: python, random

Here is my code:

```
import random

def stock_sim(price,time,mu,std):
    y=range(time)
    for i in y:
        y[i]=price+random.lognormvariate(mu,std)
    return y

print(stock_sim(100,5,0,.2))
```

It returns:

```
[101.44054391531468, 100.73246087607879, 101.00880842134261, 101.14332126597128, 100.79412638906443]
```

I need it to return:

```
[100, 101.44054391531468, 100.73246087607879, 101.00880842134261, 101.14332126597128]
```

The first value should be the intial price on first day and then the following 4 changed prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility would be

```
def stock_sim(price,time,mu,std):
    return [price]+[price + random.lognormvariate(mu,std) for i in range(time)]
```

There are many other ways, one could be to insert an item to the left, or create the list beforehand in the other solutions.

```
def stock_sim(price,time,mu,std):
    temp = [price + random.lognormvariate(mu,std) for i in range(time)]
    temp.insert(0,price)
    return temp
```

I am not sure how big your lists will grow and if performance can be an issue. In this case a deque would be the better solution

```
from collections import deque
def stock_sim(price,time,mu,std):
    temp = deque([price + random.lognormvariate(mu,std) for i in range(time)])
    temp.appendleft(price)
    return temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Just keep a separate list and add price first:

```
def stock_sim(price,time,mu,std):
    y = []
    y.append(price)
    for i in range(time):
        y.append(price+random.lognormvariate(mu,std))
    return y
```

Comment: Compared to the requested answer, this returns one too many items. Perhaps `range(1, time)` instead?

Comment: @sharth, not sure if the OP missed  an entry or not, it seems the last value is missing in the second list

Comment: range(1, time) eliminated the extra day. Thanks.

Comment: When the contents of a for-loop are unrelated to the loop variable, it's common to see `for i in range(1, time)` rewritten as `for _ in range(1, time)`.